# For finite set $S$, is there a formula for the number of endofunctions that are idempotent?

Tags: combinatorics

**Definition**:
An endofunction $f: A \rightarrow A$ is *idempotent* if $f(f(x)) = f(x)$.

**Question**:
Is there a formula for the number of endofunctions that are idempotent for a finite set?

Comment: The fixed-point set is the same as the image of $f$.  So, first choose a subset to fix, then map everything else there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every point in the range must have $f(x)=x,$ so the function is fully determined by the range, and where the points not in the range go. So say you choose $k$ points to be the range. Then, you can take each of the other $(n-k)$ points to any one of the $k$ points in the range. So there are $k^{n-k}$ choices here. So we have $$ \sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k} {n\choose k}$$ functions.

Comment: Brilliant. Is there a closed form expression for the above?

Comment: @asfeynman No idea. (Also, caveat emptor: I'm fairly confident, but by no means positive about the answer itself. There may be some subtle over-counting I'm missing, so I'd check it.)

Comment: Hah, I will check it tomorrow morning :)

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000248

Comment: If you change $\sum_{k=1}^n$ to $\sum_{k=0}^n$ then the formula will also give the correct result $1$ when $n=0$.

Comment: @bof, of course there's an OEIS sequence! Also, for your last statement, when $n=0$, the only function is the empty function, correct? Is the empty function considered idempotent? I suppose, it certainly makes sense.

Comment: @asfeynman Not bof, but yes, that’s correct (idempotentcy is a “for all” statement on the domain, so vacuously true when the domain is empty.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ahh, I see.