# Simplified form of a combinatoric sum : $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k} \binom {n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let $E$ be a set, such that $|E|=n$. We consider the set $I_n=\{ f:E\to E \; | \; f\circ f = f\}$ and for all $k=1,\dots,n$, the set $A_k=\{f \in I_n$ : $f$ has exactly $k$ fixed points}.
First, I needed to determine the cardinality of $A_k$, so I considered the surjective mapping :
\begin{align}
\Psi :& A_k \to C^k(E) \\
      &f \mapsto\{x\in E  : f(x)=x\}
\end{align}
such that $C^k(E)$ is the set of the subsets of $E$ that have $k$ elements, note that $|C^k(E)|=\binom{n}{k}$.
For all $K=\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ in $C^k(E)$, we can construct a preimage of $K$ by creating a function that maps all the $x_i$ to themselves, and have it map all the other elements of $E$ to $K$ (we can show that $f(E)=\Psi(f)$) so in other words :
\begin{equation}      \Psi^{-1}(K)=\{f : f|_K=Id_K \; \text{ and }\; f|_{E-K}\in K^{E-K} \}
\end{equation}
where $K^{E-K}$ is the set of mappings from $E-K$ to $K$. Therefore, $|\Psi^{-1}(K)|=|K^{E-K}|=k^{n-k}$. Therefore :
\begin{equation}
|A_k|=\left|\bigcup\limits_{K\in C^k(E)}\Psi^{-1}(K)\right|=\sum_{K\in C^k(E)} |\Psi^{-1}(K)| =\sum_{K\in C^k(E)}k^{n-k}=k^{n-k} |C^k(E)|=k^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}
\end{equation}
And since the $A_k$'s form a partition of $I_n$, so :
\begin{equation}
|I_n|=\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \right|=\sum_{k=1}^n |A_k|=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} 
\end{equation}
So, this is where this sum comes from. I tried using that $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, but it seems to get complicated pretty quickly, so I wonder if this sum has a simplified form, or rather I made a mistake in my reasoning and got the wrong expression. Any help is welcome.

Comment: At [OEIS A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248) there is no simpler form.

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/319361/573047), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3117704/573047),  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966955/573047),  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1251819/573047),  [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2309155p18337228), anything simpler.

Answer (score 1):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
k![z^k]e^{qz}=k![z^k]\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(qz)^j}{j!}=q^k\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(n-k)![z^{n-k}]e^{kz}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^n]\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{k!}z^ke^{kz}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n![z^n]\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(ze^z\right)^k}{k!}}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (4) we see we have the first terms of the series expansion of $ze^z$ at $0$.

> We find in OEIS the entry *[A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248)* with synopsis *Expansion of e.g.f. $\exp(x\exp(x))$* which corresponds to (4) . We do not expect any further simplification of this expression.